# How to achieve a data structure like "QHash<int, Foo> bar;" where "bar[10]" returns all "Foo" belonging to keys of 10 or less?

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, range, key-value

It does not have to be a QHash; just an existing data structure (ideally in Qt) which cleanly accomplishes that task without being considered an esoteric solution, because I need this code to be quite short (to fit on a small playing card) and easily understandable. Vectors, Multi-hashes, Lists, Maps, or anything is welcome, as long as it would be considered good practice.

Basically, I have a class which has an integer value associated with it. For example:

```
class Flowers { 
public: 
    const int m_Cost; 
    Flowers(int cost) { m_Cost = cost; }
}

Flowers roses{5};
Flowers violets{7};
Flowers tulips{9};
Flowers posies{3};

/* Place them in some sort of datastructure. */

flowerDataStructure[4]; // Returns Posies
flowerDataStructure[7]; // Returns Violets, Roses, Posies
flowerDataStructure[roses.m_Cost]; // Returns Roses, Posies
```

Would they perhaps support a range such as,

```
flowerDataStructure[5 ... 11]; // Returns Roses, Violets, Tulips
```

PS: `int m_Cost;` does not have to be `const`. I just assumed it would be easier if it was.

Thanks.

Comment: `std::map<int, Flowers>` would work or `std::set<Flowers>` if `Flowers` have proper comparison functions that order by `m_Cost`.

Comment: put them into a vector, sort them, find the iterator `it` that points to the last element with `m_Cost <= 10` then the elements you are looking for are `begin` till `it`.

Comment: btw ... what kind of requirement is it "to fit on a small playing card"? Can I choose the font size?

Comment: @tobi303 haha, I am working on a card game concept (Who knows if I will be successful?) that teaches people how read code, by writing the instructions all in a code format. http://i.imgur.com/1Wx0mcA.jpg

Comment: @Akiva cool stuff. Good luck with that.

Comment: @Akiva btw in case you need help with reviewing the code for the game or anything like that, I would be glad to help ( I love games :)

Comment: @tobi303 I will keep that in mind. It would be helpful actually if you are familiar with the Dominion Card Game.

Comment: @Akiva I played it a lot online when it was still for free, but in real I didnt like it too much.

Comment: @tobi303 Back in the isotropic days? Oh wow, you would be enormously useful in that case. Like you, I stopped playing after they shut that down.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154255/discussion-between-tobi303-and-akiva).

Answer (score 0):

> How to achieve a data structure like “QHash bar;” where
>   “bar[10]” returns all “Foo” belonging to keys of 10 or less?

The right datastructure for the collection of non-unique items sorted by integral value would be either `std::multimap` or `std::multiset` depending on how we store the key. According to the authors example above the key is stored with the data type so I have chosen `std::multiset`:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <QDebug>

struct Flower
{
public:
    const int m_cost;
    const std::string m_name;

    explicit Flower(int cost) : m_cost(cost) {}
    Flower(const char* name, int cost) : m_cost(cost), m_name(name) {}
};


int main()
{
    auto lessFunc = [](const Flower& l, const Flower& r) -> bool
                    {return l.m_cost < r.m_cost;};

    std::multiset<Flower, decltype(lessFunc)> multiSet(lessFunc);

    multiSet.emplace("roses", 5);
    multiSet.emplace("violets", 7);
    multiSet.emplace("tulips", 9);
    multiSet.emplace("posies", 3);

    // This is a request for items equal or below 7
    const auto& itEnd = multiSet.upper_bound(Flower{7});

    for(auto it = multiSet.begin(); it != itEnd; it++)
    {
        const Flower& flower{*it};
        qDebug() << flower.m_name.c_str() << flower.m_cost;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

If operator [upper_bound] desired then it can be done but we have to overload `std::multiset` (more work).

Comment: This doesn't need to be `multiset`, if the keys are (must be?) unique then `set` works better, it too has `upper_bound`

Comment: Does `int m_cost` (per author's question) suggest you only one item can be tied to price? And that is the key, btw. No same price for different flowers? Also not sure why 'better' when different but never mind.